# Symfony DoctrineExtensions softdeletable returns deleted entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, soft-delete

I installed stof/DoctrineExtensions in my symfony app and configured everything as it should.

When I remove an entity, the deletedAt is set and everything works, but then when I do findAll the deleted entities are still returned.

```
  $zorgboer = $em->getRepository('stroPublicBundle:Zorgboerderij')->find(3);

  $em->remove($zorgboer);
  $em->flush();

  $zorgboeren = $em->getRepository('stroPublicBundle:Zorgboerderij')->findAll();
```

@EDIT: OK I found the solution. the problem was that entity Zorgboerderij extends another entity. The softdeletable had to be on the parent. Now it works

Comment: Is the filter added to your doctrine config?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to setup `SoftDeleteableFilter` in app/config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    ...
    orm:
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
```

This will enable the SoftDeleteable filter, so entities which were "soft-deleted" will not appear in results.